# Input type number allows a user to delete number and have an empty input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angularJS with [rzSlider](http://angular-slider.github.io/angularjs-slider/) to allow a user to manually enter a number value or use the slider which will then populate the input. The problem is when they drag the slider and then delete the entire input from the input field the rzslider floor goes to undefined or NaN. I'm using a directive to draw out the HTML.

[image]
[image]

HTML:

```
'<div class="form-group position-relative mb-5">' +
     '<label class="mb-3 calculatorLabel">How much are you looking to borrow? <a tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="How Much Can you Borrow" data-content="And here\'s some amazing content. It\'s very engaging. Right?"><i class="far fa-question-circle"></i></a></label>' +
     '<input class="form-control form-control-lg text-transform-none" type="number" min="0" ng-required="true" title="Please Enter loan amount" maxlength="7" ng-model="model.autoLoan.borrowAmount">' +
     '<rzslider rz-slider-model="model.autoLoan.borrowAmount" rz-slider-options="model.autoLoan.slider.borrowAmount.options"></rzslider>' +
'</div>' +
```

Comment: try `ng-model="model.autoLoan.borrowAmount || 0"`

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @holydragon hey that worked! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `ng-model="model.autoLoan.borrowAmount || 0"` corrected the issue thanks @holydragon